# How do I manually set the value of a custom EnumProperty in python?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a custom enum property which defines the colour channels RGB, or RGBA depending on whether a flag in the addon preferences is enabled. Because the only way I could get this to work was to define the enum items dynamically using a function, I cannot set the default value of the enum. However, I'd really like to enable all the channels by default. Is there a way, and a sensible location in my addon's code that I can set the value of the enum after it has been registered and without requiring user interaction?

This is my EnumProperty:

```
active_channels = EnumProperty(
  name="Active Channels",
  options={'ENUM_FLAG'},
  items=channel_items,
  update=update_rgba,
  )
```

This is the function I'm using to populate it:

```
def channel_items(self, context):
  prefs = context.user_preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
  if prefs.alpha_support:
    return ((red_id, "R", ""), (green_id, "G", ""), (blue_id, "B", ""),(alpha_id, "A", ""))
  return ((red_id, "R", ""), (green_id, "G", ""), (blue_id, "B", ""))
```

Is there some way I can set the value of the enum in the addon's Panel code or on registration?

Comment: Do you mean that the addon should return the rgba enum by default, or do you want to set one of the channels, like 'g', by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check if a `bpy.prop` property has been initialized by looking at its custom property "data store".**

Have a look at the [Getter / Setter examples for `bpy.props`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html?highlight=removeproperty#get-set-example).  The `ENUM_FLAG` option enum property is saved internally as a custom property of the same name,  an integer, calculated from each item having an "internal id" of a power of `2` (aka [bitwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)). `1, 2, 4, 8...`  The empty set `set()` `0`, first only `1`, first and second `1 | 2`, and third `1 | 2 | 4` ...

As an example I've used the items method to show how to alter the data store (the custom property) only if it hasn't been already set.  I've used a scene bool to emulate the addon prefs boolean.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, EnumProperty


def channel_items(self, context):
    prefs = context.scene    

    red_id, green_id, blue_id, alpha_id = (c for c in "rgba")
    items = [(red_id, "R", ""),
            (green_id, "G", ""), 
            (blue_id, "B", "")]
    if prefs.alpha_support:
        items.append((alpha_id, "A", ""))

    if not self.get("active_channels"):
        self["active_channels"] = 1 | 2 | 4 #rgb
        if prefs.alpha_support:
            self["active_channels"] |= 8

    return items

def update_rgba(self, context):
    print("enum set", self.active_channels, "int", self["active_channels"])
    return None

active_channels = EnumProperty(
    name="Active Channels",
    options={'ENUM_FLAG'},
    items=channel_items,
    update=update_rgba,
)
bpy.types.Scene.active_channels = active_channels
bpy.types.Scene.alpha_support = BoolProperty(default=False)
```

Note the above will give all for empty selection, as well as the custom property not being set.  To check if `bpy.prop` is initialized would use

```
is_init = self.get("active_channels") is not None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry I didn't notice I left some irrelevant stuff in my question code snippets. I'll see if I can incorporate it into the add-on and I'll also try to make sure the code I have written adheres to the Blender coding guidelines.

Comment: NP on both.  I try  to provide a minimal runable solution.  Can't see why this wont work wired up in addon. Just remember you cant change properties in restricted context, like in a register method. Should be ok in items and definitely in setter and getter.